# Network Icon suddenly shows a "?"

Tags: networking, icons, 18.10, websites

I use ubuntu 18.10 on my computer and I've been getting a weird error since a few days ago. Suddenly, my network icon turns into the version with "?", and I can't acess some websites. No problem on other devices, only on the computer. I'm using a wired connection, and don't have any idea of what could be causing the error.

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 06
       serial: 94:de:80:f1:61:37
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.11 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fdfff000-fdffffff memory:fdff8000-fdffbfff
```

Comment: It means that you've lost Internet connectivity. Assuming that you're using ethernet... check your cabling first. If you're using wireless, try a stronger signal network.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to check it... I've never had problems with cabling that's why I didn't even consider it...

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: Ok, I've just edited it.

Comment: Try this now, so you know how it works... in `terminal` type `ping 192.168.0.1`. Observe that you're getting return pings, and the time values. Control-c to stop the pings. When you see the ?, indicating that you've lost connection, do the `ping` again, and see if you recognize the pattern. Report back.

Comment: It took a while for the error to happen... but it did. When I tried the ping command I got "Network is unreachable". That means the cabling is causing the problem, right?

Comment: Probably. 192.168.0.1 is your router, and you're not even making it to there. What kind of ethernet port is this? A PCI card? Motherboard built-in? Describe, in detail, the ethernet cabling from your ethernet port on the computer, all the way to your router.

Comment: Motherboard built-in. The router stays near the computer, the cable just goes straight from the computer to the router.

Comment: Change the ethernet cable. Use CAT 5E or 6. Then POWER cycle the router by **unplugging** it from AC power, plug it back in, wait 30 seconds, then reboot the computer.